# Changed Admin password on Azure SQL Database - login failed in Xamarin Forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Xamarin Forms app authenticating using Azure B2C. The app authenticates, and fetches data from an Azure SQL DB, displays this data in a list.

I recently had to change the sever admin password for this and whilst I could authenticate the user, I could not fetch the data from my table as I was being thrown out of authentication against the server (obviously).

I could not remember where to change the password so it took me a while and I wanted to log it in case anyone of you had the same prob...

Go to your Azure Homepage
Click on 'App Services'
Click the App Service from the list that you authenticate against with B2C.
Click on 'Data connections'
Click on 'Data Connection Details'
Password is in the 'data connection string' box.
Delete the connection String.
Create a new one with amended password.

Phew.

Comment: I did not click on "answer your own question" like I wanted to as I cannot see this option anymore with the new SO question asking format. Maybe I missed it at some stage. Sorry.

Comment: So your question is solved by the steps your post in your answer?

Comment: Yup that's right

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Azure Homepage Click on 'App Services' Click the App Service from the list that you authenticate against with B2C. Click on 'Data connections' Click on 'Data Connection Details' Password is in the 'data connection string' box. Delete the connection String. Create a new one with amended password.